# Use of とは when there doesn't seem to be comparison

Tags: grammar, particles

I've seen とは used for the first time and understand from the explanation given on this question, [What are the uses of に and とは in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/what-are-the-uses-of-%E3%81%AB-and-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF-in-this-sentence) that とは is (or at least in one specific type of context) is used to mean to/from, and as such makes a kind of comparison.

However, I don't see how that applies to this sentence:

> 人生とはなにかを考えた。

The most meaningful thing I can imagine this would means is something like: I thought of something relating to life - which is still a bit iffy to me.

Is there another use of とは when there doesn't seem to be comparison?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, when introducing a topic/defining something.
You can [find the definition here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/17197/meaning/m0u/).

> 定義{ていぎ}・[主題化]{しゅだいか}を表わす
>   (To indicate a definition or topic)

So based on that, a literal translation of 人生とはなにかを考えた。 would be something like "I thought about the definition of life".

You can find this usage *a lot*, so I highly recommend remembering it.
Even a quick google of とは you will find tons of hits for various sites.
You can also use it as a type of question marker like `T-SQLとは?` meaning "What is T-SQL?". I find it's usage in wikipedia or dictionary sites often as they give definitions for things.

Also, note that `とは` is a rigid form usually used in writing and the more colloquial form is `というのは`.

There also is another usage of `とは` when used to expressed that you are surprised. For example, `こんなところにあったとは！` to mean "I can't believe it was in this place!" (for example in astonishment when you are going to a place you never are been before and surprised at where it is located). * Note this version cannot be replaced by `というのは` like the first definition).