# Translation for [竜とは逃げぬものなれば]

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, classical-japanese

new in the language so I am having a hard time figuring out the meaning of this sentence. 'When it comes to dragons, you can't escape' would be my translation, but pretty sure I am wrong. If it doesn't take too much time, please give me a brief explanation about the grammar. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sentence is using the grammar of [classical/archaic Japanese](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/kobun-reading-introduction/). This sentence can be translated to modern Japanese as 竜とは逃げないものなので or 竜とは逃げないものですから.

- **竜**: "dragon"
- **とは**: quotative と + thematic は, used to give a definition or an important characteristic of something. See: [Use of とは when there doesn't seem to be comparison](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38576/5010)
- **逃げ**: "escape", the 未然形 ("irrealis form") of 逃ぐ, which is an archaic version of 逃げる
- **ぬ**: "not", the 連体形 ("attributive form") of ず, which is an archaic negation marker (≒modern ない)
- **もの**: "thing", "existence"
- **なれ**: "is", the 已然形 ("realis form") of なり, which is an archaic copula (≒modern です/だ)
- **ば**: "because", an archaic reason marker (≒modern ので/から)

> 竜とは逃げぬものなれば。
>   (It's) because a dragon is an existence that does not escape.
>   (It's) because dragons won't escape (from you).

Comment: Ohhh, meaning they won't run away since they are strong beings. Thank you very much, your detailed explanation helps a lot.^^